# Merge tags tunnel and tunneling

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

As per the title. There doesn't seem to me to be enough difference in meaning to have both tags.

Comment: Always with the tunneling!

Comment: @Shane, that's an extraordinarily odd comment. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Erm, sorry.  Futurama reference.  Ignore me.

Comment: @Shane, I'm a Futurama fan (I have them all) but I don't recall that expression as anything out of the ordinary (if Futurama and ordinary can even be used in the same sentence).

Comment: [This one](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1054486/), I think.  "The Tunneling Horror?  I hate that guy!  Always with the tunneling!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is complete [tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tunnel) was merged into [tunneling](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tunneling).

Comment: Strange, I marked this as accepted yesterday and this morning that mark is clear. Let's try that again.